# How to I include multiple remote git repo's into a single repo?

Tags: git, merge

Trying to come up with the logic and the standard way to do this.

Example.

**Remote Repo called "A"**

This repo is cloned as "Local A" and and maintains 2 remotes, one master and one upstream. Upstream changes (A) are merged with "Local A" master and pushed. All good.

**Remote Repo called "B"**

These repo files needs to be included in "Local A"  in a sub-directory.

Do I simply add another remote repo to this sub directory and fetch, merge? Is that how it is done normally?

ps. I do not want to use submodules, I simply want to pull files from multiple remotes into one master git, but also have them retain and "upstream" remote to pull in updates and then merge and push to one master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is at github: http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/

If you need to move directory, just move it as you normally would. If you need to change the history, that's trickier, but you can find description here: http://help.github.com/split-a-subpath-into-a-new-repo/

Answer (score 2):

Another way to accomplish that is to use submodules. According to how you are exactly going to use it you should decide which method will better fulfill your needs.

A very good explanation of [submodules](http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html) and [subtree merging](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html) and when to use those is available on [progit.org](http://progit.org/).

- Submodules: http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html
- Subtree merging: http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html